# influxdb : Display over a 24 hour period whether a machine is off, idle or on

Tags: influxdb, grafana

I’m new to influx and grafana and want to know in terms of percentage over a 24 hour period on whether the machine is off, idle or on.  This is a IOT project and we're recording the state (off, idle on) by the power used.  The data ends up being stored in influx under state as either 0 = off, 1 = idle and 2 = on. How can I achieve this in influx query or Grafana? Any pointers or help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [pie chart plugin](https://grafana.com/plugins/grafana-piechart-panel/installation) to show the three states and respective percentages over time. You can do something like:

```
SELECT mean("value") FROM "state" WHERE value=[0|1|2] GROUP BY time($__interval) fill(null)
```

For each part of the chart.

Comment: Thanks.  Is that calculating the time in each state or just how many values for each state?

Comment: It was just for the sake of understanding, you should have three different queries, one for each value. :) so, value=0, value=1 and value=2

Comment: Its appreciated.   I take it this method just counts the amount of times the states occurs and then displays the percentage rather than the time between changes of state?

Comment: Per your question ("in terms of percentage over a 24 hour period on whether the machine is off, idle or on."), with this method it would be possible to obtain the amount of times that state happened during the specified period.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [grafana-discrete-panel](https://github.com/NatelEnergy/grafana-discrete-panel) (also available in official grafana plugin repository). It is designed specially to visualize state changes in time.

Comment: Thanks, that's more like I want to see :-)  i don't seam to be able to get the 0,1,2 mappings to off,idle, on to work? it just shows the original 0,1,2.  any ideas?

Comment: You can use 'Mappings' tab in panel editor to map values to strings, and 'Colors' tab to map values to colors of your choice.